# bootstrap4 navbar with fullscreen overlay

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want the bootstrap 4 navigation bar to stay fully expanded. Also I would like to have an overlay element where the image and text is aligned to the right. i.e the clickable img/text "All categories", is aligned to the right.

Here is what I have. I cannot get the text to go to the right.

```css
.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  
  <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
  
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="img/icons/logo/pquizlogo.svg" width="38" height="38" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">Brand-name
    </a>
    <div>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; All categories</span>
      <script>
      function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
      }
      function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
      }
      </script>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Please tell me if the HTML is alright, and how to make 'All categories' show up to the right of the navbar.

thanks!

Comment: .overlay a { text-align: right; } ?

Comment: tried that, doesn't work. i added { text-align: right; }  and { float: right; } to most classes, with no result.

Comment: Check the answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: That answer didn't work. Here is what did: Adding the 'mr-auto' class to the image link on the left. <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#">

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the span element to `display:block;` and then you can use `text-align: right;`.

I added a class `nav-icon` to the span and moved your inline style to the css section:

```css
.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

.nav-icon{
     font-size:30px;
     cursor:pointer;
     display: block;
     text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  
  <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
  
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="img/icons/logo/pquizlogo.svg" width="38" height="38" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">Brand-name
    </a>
    <div>
    <span class="nav-icon" onclick="openNav()">All categories &#9776;</span>
      <script>
      function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
      }
      function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
      }
      </script>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```