# Slide overlay in

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a nav overlay I'm trying to slide in from the top of the screen using CSS, I can't figure out the Z index

Here is my attempt so far;

```
#nav-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  transform: translateZ(250px);
  background: #191919;
  border-left: 1px solid fade-out( #ffffff, 0.9);
}
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: how about you check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47488474/

Comment: You should add your html.